# web service client encounters a 'java.net.SocketException: Connection reset'

Tags: tcp, connection, reset

**problem**

We have a java ee app deployed on Weblogic server 10.3.1 which provides HTTP web service. Let's just call it 'server'. Another java app deployed on tomcat on another machine, which will make web service calls to the server, Let's just call it 'client'. Both the client and the server app are using Axis.

There are chances that the client will fail with an exception

```
"java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)",
```

and 1 minute later the a server app log shows:

```
org.apache.axis.Message ERROR  - 
java.io.IOException: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
     at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:99).
```

It failed no more than 5 times a day. The total web service request on the server is less, like, several hundreds. And it seems it tend to fail after the server has a long time 'rest': The first call on every morning will probably fail (we don't have business services at night).

**The exceptions stacks are:**

Client side:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:66)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager$RewindableInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:375)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
... 12 more
```

Server side:

```
2013-03-06 08:37:29,491 org.apache.axis.Message ERROR  - java.io.IOException:
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:99)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:137)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.writeChunkNoTransfer(ChunkOutput.java:530)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.writeChunks(ChunkOutput.java:487)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.flush(ChunkOutput.java:382)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.CharsetChunkOutput.flush(CharsetChunkOutput.java:315)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput$2.checkForFlush(ChunkOutput.java:580)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.CharsetChunkOutput.write(CharsetChunkOutput.java:222)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutputWrapper.write(ChunkOutputWrapper.java:146)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletOutputStreamImpl.write(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:138)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ByteArray.writeTo(ByteArray.java:375)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.writeTo(SOAPPart.java:265)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.writeTo(Message.java:539)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.sendResponse(AxisServlet.java:902)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:777)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:821)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:170)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:168)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
    at com.ulic.ucia.framework.util.AppFilter.doFilter(AppFilter.java:48)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
    at com.ebao.pub.framework.AppFilter.doFilter(AppFilter.java:101)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3588)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2200)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2106)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1428)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

When the client fails, we check the app log and the database, and it turns out that the business transaction is always success. Weblogic server somehow fails to write the HTTP response. And Weblogic server log file says:

BEA 101366 The server could not send the HTTP message during the configured timeout value. The socket has been closed.

**Sorted logs and some analyses**

Both the servers have ntp service. I simplified and sorted the server logs and the client logs by time to get a clearer view,

```
2013-03-06 08:36:18,755  Web Service Client      began it's work
2013-03-06 08:36:18,758  Web Service Client  make http calls and wait for response
2013-03-06 08:36:19,039  APP on WLS         received request
2013-03-06 08:36:24,553  APP on WLS         app log says transaction finished with a success.
2013-03-06 08:36:24,575  Web Service Client received java.net.SocketException: Connection reset” 
2013-03-06 08:37:29,491  APP on WLS      org.apache.axis.Message ERROR  - java.io.IOException:java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
```

Most notably, the client received a Connection Reset after 6 seconds of waiting when the server app just finished proceeding. So I think it must has something to do with the server. The server machine sended a 'TCP RST' when weblogic was trying to send http response due to some reason, but what is that reason?
    For all I know , there are two scenarios (may be more) the 'RST' will be send in an java application. 
    Java thread ends without closing the socket, the tcp stack will send a 'RST' to the socket on the other hand to indicate an error
    Tcp stack failed to send all data after 'linger' time.

And now my brain has stucked, don't know what to do next. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: When the socket was closed actively, and then the program still try to write data to socket output stream, it will get a "java.net.SocketException: Socket closed". I've just test it with a simple java code. So, is that means there is a possibility that, may be, it's because of a weblogic server bug?

Comment: The key message here is the server failing  to write the response within the timeout. Check the server configuration, as hinted in the message. Everything after that follows directly from this.

Answer (score -1):

try to setup axis 2 CHUNKED property of HTTP connection in false. Some web servers can't process HTTP without content length header and client fails with Socket Exception.

```
serviceProxy = new FunctionsServiceStub( ... );
Options options = serviceProxy._getServiceClient().getOptions();
options.setProperty( org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.CHUNKED, Boolean.FALSE );
```

Comment: Our client is using axis 1.3 which works on HTTP/1.0, and HTTP/1.0 doesn't support CHUNKED mod.

Comment: The error occurs when writing  the response. *Ergo* it has nothing to do with the request.